# Issue with playing music file during a phone calling iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I have two pieces of code:

Code 1 - This is playing a music file via the in-ear speaker:

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"8Ocean.mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:tileDirectory];
NSError *error=nil;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if(!error)
{
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Code 2- This is playing a music file during a phone call (is routed to in-ear or speaker phone depending on user setting during the phone call)

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"8Ocean.mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:tileDirectory];
NSError *error=nil;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if(!error)
{
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.audioPlayer.volume=10.0;
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

My issue is:

Code 1 and 2 work well independently. However, after using code 1, code 2 will not work at all (unless the app is killed and restarted)

I have tried everything I can think of but cannot work out where the problem is from.

Comment: Please arrange your code with proper formate and please clarify what do you want to achieve with that

Comment: I would like to offer the user the ability to play music via the in-ear speaker at any time. Even during a phone call, the user can play music via in-ear speaker (if the user decides to have his phone conversation on speaker phone then the music will also play on speaker phone)."

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to handle audio session interruptions from phone calls in order for audio processing not to be killed for your app.

Comment: hotpaw2: Can you please elaborate a little more which audio interruption is caused this situation during phone call. It would be a great help if you past some piece of code here. Many Thanks :)